# redirect_to the previous page but changing the language

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What am I trying to do? To redirect the user in the previous page with the website translated in new language selected

My previous script was (language_controller):

```
class LanguagesController < ApplicationController
 def edit
     @language = Language.find_by(locale: I18n.locale)
     render layout: false
 end

 def update
     @language = Language.find(update_params[:id])
     if user_signed_in?
       setting = current_user.setting || current_user.build_setting
   setting.language = @language.id
       setting.save
     end
     redirect_to root_path(locale: @language.locale)
   end

    private
    def update_params
     params.require(:language).permit(:id)
   end
 end
```

As you can see, there is `redirect_to root_path` that redirect the user in the home page. Even if he is changing the language in an article-page

So I edit it and I added in edit `session[:return_to] ||= request.referer`

and in my update action I replaced `redirect_to root_path(locale: @language.locale)`
with `redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)`

What is happening? If the user is logged, it works very good and it redirects the user in the previous page.

If the user is not logged he is redirected in previous page BUT now the language is the same. Probably because I removed `(locale: @language.locale)`, right?

I also try to edit redirect_to in this way: `redirect_to session.delete(:return_to, locale: @language.locale)`
but it said that I can not add two elements there.

How to solve?

Comment: Can you please provide addition information? How is location is stored when there is no user? Always in path, like /en/posts? What is your version of Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @AndreyArtemyev , Rails 5.0.7.2. Always in path like /en/posts